# Background of canvas unintentionally coming to front

Tags: node.js, canvas, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have 9 slots which I want to be able to fill with elements during the conversation in my action. The `frame()` function designs the background of my interactive canvas. Therefore I want to call it **once** in the beginning. The problem is that when I draw the second element, the previous one disappears. I already figured out the reason for this.. `frame()` seems to redraw the background every time.

I tried calling the frame() in the callback for the `Default Welcome Intent` but nothing changed. Also I made the functions `noop()` and `foo()` to call `frame()` only once.. without results. 
Then I tried to redraw the previous elements every time after bringing the background to front but that didn't work too.
I also couldn't recreate the slots in the index.html with `div`. The rectangles appeared above or below the whole canvas frame.

Does somebody know how to solve this? Or do you think the easiest solution is to create a `.jpg` of the background and set it as `style="background url('...')"` of the canvas in the html file.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
'use strict;'
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// failed attempt to redraw previous elements after
// unintentionally bringing background to front:
var prevReqs=[]; //see line 26 and 78

var iD=1;
var requirements = [
  new Requirement(50,50),
  new Requirement(500,50),
  new Requirement(950,50),
  new Requirement(50,250),
  new Requirement(500,250),
  new Requirement(950,250),
  new Requirement(50,450),
  new Requirement(500,450),
  new Requirement(950,450),
];

const callbacks = {
  onUpdate(state) {
    if ('iD' in state) {
      iD = state.iD;
      // prevReqs.push(iD);
      drawRec();
    }
  },
};

function drawRec(){
  requestAnimationFrame(drawRec); //enable drawing
  requirements[iD-1].drawRequirement();
}

function Requirement(xCoord,yCoord){
  this.xCoord=xCoord;
  this.yCoord=yCoord;
  this.drawRequirement = function(){ //draw the element
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth="1";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    ctx.rect(xCoord,yCoord,200,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.moveTo(xCoord,yCoord+33);
    ctx.lineTo(xCoord+200,yCoord+33);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText("id: "+iD, xCoord+5, yCoord+47);
  }
}

//background... the problematic function
function frame(){
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  ctx.fillStyle="#D6EAF8";
  ctx.strokeStyle="#D6EAF8";
  ctx.rect(0,0,1200,600);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
  for(let i=0;i<requirements.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(requirements[i].xCoord,requirements[i].yCoord,200,100);
    ctx.font = "64px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#DCDCDC";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#DCDCDC";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.lineWidth = "6";
    ctx.fillText(i+1, requirements[i].xCoord+100, requirements[i].yCoord+72);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  // for(let p=0;p<prevReqs.length;p++){
  //    if(prevReqs[p]!=null){
  //     requirements[prevReqs[p]].drawRequirement();
  //    }
  // }
}

// attempt to call frame() only once
function noop() {};
function foo() {
    foo = noop;
    frame();
}
foo();

// frame(); //?

drawRec(); //uncomment to test in html
assistantCanvas.ready(callbacks);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        canvas {
            border: 6px solid navy;
            background: #D6EAF8;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Disable favicon requests -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/x-icon;,">

    <!-- Load Assistant Canvas CSS and JavaScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/assistant/immersivecanvas/css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/assistant/immersivecanvas/js/immersive_canvas_api.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="1200" height="600" padding-left="56px"></canvas>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/log.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
'use strict';

const {
  dialogflow,
  Suggestions,
  ImmersiveResponse,
} = require('actions-on-google');
// Import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'Default Welcome Intent'.
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.ask('Hello');
  conv.ask(new ImmersiveResponse({
    url: `https://${firebaseConfig.projectId}.firebaseapp.com`,
  }));
});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'PlaceElement'
app.intent('PlaceElement', (conv, {number}) => {
  if(number>0 && number<10){
    conv.ask('Ok...');
    conv.ask(new ImmersiveResponse({
      state: {
        iD: number,
      },
    }));
  }
  else {
    conv.ask('Wrong input.');
  }
});

exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Can you [update your question](edit) to include the code you're using on the webhook that is initializing the interactive canvas and updating the state?

Comment: Oh sure, sorry. Updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) doesn't do what you think it is doing (judging by how you're using it and your comments next to it). It does **not** "enable drawing".

What it does do is request that the function so named be called before the next time the rendering engine is about to do a repaint. This can be used to update animation (hence the name), but also has non-animation uses. When used in animation, you typically have the function that does the drawing call `requestAnimationFrame()` naming the same function again - putting it into an endless loop.

That is what you're doing here. You *think* you're just calling `frame()` once, but since, inside that, you have the line

```
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

it will render what you have in the function and then, before it re-renders the layout (which it typically is willing to do 60 or so times per second), it re-calls your function. Over and over.

So the reason `frame()` keeps getting called is because it requests that it keep getting called.

You have a couple of approaches to this, depending on your actual needs:

1. Just drop that line. It isn't necessary unless you are doing animation.
2. If you *are* doing animation based on the value of `iD`, then your `onUpdate` could just set the value of `iD` and have `frame()` draw things based on the iD.

As an aside, this isn't true in your case, but one reason to post the webhook code is to see exactly what you were sending in your `ImmersiveResponse` object. If you were sending the `url` parameter each time, then you *would* have been reloading the page (and thus redrawing the background) each time.